# How to remap F4 to F11 on Chromebook

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, chromebook

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a Toshiba Chromebook. The keyboard has no F11 key. The F4 key has the fullscreen icon because thats what Chrome OS uses, so I would like to use that to make applications fullscreen. I'm mostly talking about Chromium right now.

I've been playing around with `xmodmap` and I've seen alot of stuff talking about Ctrl, Super and Alt, but those seem to be different than F* and most other keys.

This is the last thing I tried:

```
:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep F11 
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep F4
keycode  70 = F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 F4 XF86Switch_VT_4
:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 70 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11"
:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep 70
keycode  70 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
```

After this F4 still doesn't make Chromium full screen. I don't really know what I'm doing, just picking and choosing from Google and `man xmodmap`.

How can I make F4 act like F11 for applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd approach that is to open Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom, and add a new shortcut, linking it to the following command

```
bash -c "xdotool getactivewindow key F11"
```

You will need `xdotool` to be installed , so run `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

This has limitations, howver. This works only in GUI, won't work in TTY1 or terminal emulators.

Comment: That's works perfectly! I'm only concerned with the GUI for this so it totally fits the bill. Thanks a lot.